# how to export pdf with datatables using custom buttons

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

How do I export table data using a custom button and how to remove the button that is labeled, like the picture below ?

[image]

I have tried the code below, but when I click the pdf button. no pdf export event. Thank you

Html button:

```
<input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" ><input type="button" name="print" id="print" value="Print" class="btn btn-info" ><input type="button" name="pdf" id="pdf" value="PDF" class="btn btn-info" >
```

Javascript Datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pdf").on("click", function() {
    table.button( '.buttons-pdf' ).trigger();
}); 


 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  todayBtn:'linked',
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  autoclose: true
 });

 fetch_data('no');

 function fetch_data(is_date_search, start_date='', end_date='')
 {
  var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({
     dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
             { 
            extend: 'pdf',
        }
        ], 
   "processing" : true,
   "serverSide" : true,
   bFilter:false,
   "ajax" : {
    url:"fetch.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
     is_date_search:is_date_search, start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
    }, 
   }
  });
 }


 $('#search').click(function(){
  var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
  var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
  if(start_date != '' && end_date !='')
  {
   $('#order_data').DataTable().destroy();
   fetch_data('yes', start_date, end_date);
    //$("#tabel").show(); 
    document.getElementById('tabel').style.display = "block";  
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Both Date is Required");
  }
 }); 

});
```

Error from console :
[image]

Comment: 1) why do you not style DataTables buttons instead of creating new buttons? 2) Why do you try to use a none existing variable called table, when you have a variable called dataTable you for some reason have declared in a local scope?

Comment: yes I just want to try using the button outside the table

Comment: Try look in the documentation, see https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons().container()

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but since I was struggling with the same problem I decided to provide an answer anyway.

The only way I got to make it work is using the index of the button you want to trigger. Something like this:

```
$().DataTable().buttons(0,x).trigger();
```

where `x` is the index of the button you want to click.

In the specific case shown in the question, as there is only one button in the datatable:

```
$('#order_data').DataTable().buttons(0,0).trigger();
```

would trigger the click event and export the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Please change the `src` for the jquery file and test it yourself once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>abc</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <table id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Features</th>
                        <th>Report</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="../assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf','print'
            ]
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Please see if you have imported all the files mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, I have imported all the files datatables libraries. What if I use the button that I made myself, like the picture above

Comment: Is there any error in the console when clicking on the PDF button ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error on the console in the post above

Comment: You should change `table.button( '.buttons-pdf' ).trigger();` line to `dataTable.button( '.buttons-pdf' ).trigger();`as dataTable is the object used to initialize the DataTable class .

Comment: Please try the updated code i've provided above. I've tested it on my system. Do change the jquery file src and test it once.

Comment: from your code using the export button from the datatable, my question means using buttons outside the table to export data